# Is qApp->exec() valid if using a QApplication

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication, qcoreapplication

Is it valid to call `qApp->exec()` or `QCoreApplication::exec()` if I'm using a `QApplication` instance? Since it's a static function, in both cases `QCoreApplication::exec()` will be called. However, it appears that even if I call one of them, my `QApplication` based program works just fine - is this just luck/coincidence or is it ment to be valid?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

It is not luck since static functions should behave like normal non-virtual functions also.

Long answer:

A static function is a member function that does not use *this* pointer. When you are calling it from an object it behaves like a normal member.

Since QAppliction is derived from QCoreApplication and exec() is a member of QCoreApplication, it is also a member of objects of types derived from QCoreApplication.

qApp returns a pointer to a QApplication object that is also a QCoreApplication so it also contans exec().

Comment: qApp is not a function, so you can't call it like one (i.e. qApp() is an error). The object that qApp gives you is a QCoreApplication object, not a QApplication object.

Comment: You are right, it is just a macro and using () is an error. Still, depanding on the type of application it is casted to the real type of the instance. For example, if you include QWidgets it will be casted to QApplication.

Comment: Ouch. So what qApp means depends on which headers you include. :(

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it. For some reason I thought that `QApplication` has it's own `QApplication::exec` function, but it doesn't! That makes it clear.
@Craig Scott: No, qApp always points to `QCoreApplication::instance()`

Answer (score 1):

`qApp` is simply a `#define` to `QCoreApplication::instance()`. All `qApp` is doing in your usage of it is telling the compiler where to find the `exec()` function. But because `exec()` is a static function, it isn't being called through an object, even though your code makes it look like it is. So `qApp->exec()` should be entirely equivalent to `QCoreApplication::exec()` from the compiler's point of view. That said, I don't know if the C++ standard would require `qApp` to be non-null in this case, even though it technically doesn't need to be used.

Comment: To be clear, as @dragos-pop mentioned, QApplication is just a subclass of QCoreApplication. In the original question, it makes no difference whether your application creates a QCoreApplication object or a QApplication object, you can still call exec() the same way.

Answer (score 1):

QT uses a singleton pattern on QApplication, so all your calls end up calling the single instance of QApplication. Why they chose to put qApp along for the ride is strange, but it seems the shortest string to type. I prefer keeping the pointer to the original QApplication which you created yourself.

Comment: I believe qApp is a historical hangover from the very early days of Qt. It may have begun its life as an actual global variable, but as my answer mentions, it is now just a #define for QCoreApplication::instance(). It has presumably been kept to allow older code to continue working with minimal code changes when people update to newer versions of Qt.